# Showing the existence of $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-} \frac{1-x}{1-f(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be continuous, differentiable and with $f(1)=1$ and such that $f(x)\le x$ for all $x$. Consider the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to 1^-} \frac{1-x}{1-f(x)}.
$$
Does the limit exist? If it exists, is it possible to say that it must be finite?

Comment: If it exists, it equals $\lim_\limits_{x\to1}[f'(x)]^{-1}.$.

Comment: Well, if $f$ is differentiable, the limit is simply $1/f'(1)$.

Comment: But then, what if $f'(1)=0$?

Comment: You are right. In that case we cannot say whether the limit exists without further information.

Comment: Well, we have $f(x)\le x$... so the problem would be to figure out if this additional information rules out $f'(1)=0$.

Answer (score 4):

For all $x<1$ we have that $$f(x)\le x \implies 1-x\le 1-f(x) \implies \frac{1-x}{1-f(x)}\le 1$$ (the term $1-f(x)$ is certainly positive for $x<1$ because $f(x)\le x<1$). Letting $x\to 1^-$, this implies that the limit must be less or equal than $1$. Now since the limit is equal to $1/f'(1)$ (as noted in the comments), we obtain (putting these together) that $$\frac{1}{f'(1)}\le 1 \implies 1\le f'(1)$$ so the possibility $f'(1)=0$ can be ruled out.

Comment: "this implies that the limit must be less or equal than 1", I think that before making this statement one should prove that it exists, am I missing something?

Comment: @user52227 The limit is equal to $1/f'(1)$. So, it exists, right?

Comment: I'm confused: before saying what the limit is, one should prove that the limit exists, and not the other way around... am I completely wrong?

Comment: @user52227 You say that $f$ is continuous and differentiable. Differentiable where? on $(0,1)$ or on $[0,1]$?

Comment: f is differentiable on [0,1]

Comment: @user52227 I think, that If $f$ is differentiable but not necessarily continuous differentiable, then it can be that this limit does not exist. If it exists, then it must be equal to $1/f'(1)$ but it can be that it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{f(1)-f(x)}{1-x}\to f'(1)$ but as $f(x)\le x$ we have $f'(1)\ge 1$.